# Is it possible to repair a dent on frame?

Tags: frames, repair, accidents

Hi, 
I found today dent on down tube (13/14cm from head tube).

I have two questions:

- Is it possible to repair the frame?
- Is it safe to ride the bike after this

[image]

[image]

Main frame is aluminum.

The dent is on the right side of tube and it's only one damage that I found. I bought this bike a time ago, but usually I store it in dark basement and didn't seen it before.

Comment: What's the frame material, how did the dent get there?

Comment: Is it Carbon, Aluminium, Steel or Titanium?

Comment: I think you also need to ask how your bike got dented - were you the victim of a vandal?  Attempted theft?  Or have you pranged, crashed or biffed your bike?  Did you buy it used and have only just noticed the dent?

Comment: Where is the dent relative to the the front wheel?  Is it in the "underside" of the tube, the side, or the top that you would see while riding by peering past the top tube?

Comment: Have you examined the rest of the bike for additional damage ?

Comment: Main frame are aluminum.
The dent is on the right side of tube and it's only one damage that i found.
I bought this bike a time ago, but usually i storage it in dark basement and i didn't seen it before.

Comment: @Gamer was it damaged when you bought it?  Its a lesson to be more rigorous in checking, when buying something.  It looks like crush damage from poor storage or possibly a repair stand, as opposed to crash damage from impact.

Answer (score 2):

it could be fixed cosmetically, but not structurally.

but it's not recommended to fix it, bending it over and over will cause more and more Metal fatigue. and it's a hassle to do so.

about safety, most named brand is "ok to ride" under this condition, but there is luck involved. so it's a good idea to replace that.

why I say luck - all frame are slightly diffrent, even they look the same. some will break faster, some will hold on like it was nothing, and each rider's style will change the parameter. so no one can precisely predict the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the dent would weaken it.

Sound like you have been riding it.

A dent does significantly weaken the bike.

I would ride easy.  No jumps.

Comment: Agreed - make sure that this dent doesn't grow or develop cracks in the area.  Make it a part of regular maintenance to clean and eyeball this area closely.  **If it changes** retire the frame and salvage any good parts.